# Django web based proxy

Tags: python, django, proxy

I am trying to make a django web based proxy. When the  user submits a website that they would like to visit into the search form on the website it sends out a get request to a view that collects that URL and then uses urllib2 to fetch the requested webpage. The webpage is then processed so that any links or images URL's that start with '/' will have the base URL added to the beginning.

My problem is how should I handle any forms or requests made by the web page??? If this question is too broad, could someone point me in the right direction. I don't even know where to start, I'm kind of new to web development.